# Save a text file from web site on a server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to know if I can save a text file on a folder on the server

This is the code I am using now :

```
string FileToWrite = GetContentFile();
string Path = @"C:\testfolder\";
string filename = Path + "FirstFile.txt";
File.WriteAllText(Path, FileToWrite);
```

but it seem to hang on

```
File.WriteAllText(strPath, FileToWrite);
```

is this possible at first to do ? I am using ASP.NET MVC and C#

Comment: File.WriteAllText(Path, FileToWrite); you have mistake here. I this must be File.WriteAllText(filename , FileToWrite);

Comment: Yes, and then if failed again check the permissions of the output folder

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that code you've shown will "hang" on that line. Please confirm that you use "hang" in its common meaning - "program stops at that line and does not execute past it blocking that thread" (so far looks like just mistake of using wrong variable... so post likely will be closed as "typographical error")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only passing it the folder where your file will be written, so it doesn't know what to write to. You need to include the filename in the path.

`File.WriteAllText(filename, FileToWrite);`